# how to get name of serial port in windows 10 for method SerialPort.getCommPort() in Java

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

SerialPort sp = SerialPort.getCommPort(); //<-- Here, how to know what is argument

sp.setComPortParameters(9600, 8, 1, 0);

sp.setComPortTimeouts(SerialPort.TIMEOUT_WRITE_BLOCKING, 0, 0);

Answer (score 0):

Your should get the available ports by `SerialPort[] serialPorts = SerialPort.getCommPorts();`

Then, pass one of the serialPort to parameter.

Comment: i get this error  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError